# Any way to hit multiple enemies with a charge?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I have a character in 3.5 that is decent at charging, I'd like to know if there is a way to hit multiple enemies with a single charge action. I'm taking Leap Attack on my next level, and thought it'd be cool to jump through the air and hit multiple enemies in close proximity when I land. I can enlarge myself to get reach if that helps, I also have levels in Warblade.

At this point I may make a separate character based around this concept, but I have no idea if it's even possible. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible the DM may rule that only the *first* attack at the end of charge by a creature that possesses the special ability [pounce](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monsterTypes.html#pounce) need be made against the charge's target. Ask the DM. (This DM permits such a tactic.) Multiple ways exist for a PC to get pounce, the easiest being 1 level of barbarian with the alternative class feature **spiritual totem (lion)** (*Complete Champion* 46) and the 3rd-level druid spell (or 2nd-level ranger spell) ***lion's charge*** [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 133), often put into a wand and activated with the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/skillsAll.html#use-magic-device). Further, a warblade can also take the 5th-level tiger claw maneuver **pouncing charge** [strike] (*Tome of Battle* 88) for at least one pounce per encounter.

If pounce isn't an option, by far the easiest way to hit multiple foes on a charge is with the feat [**Cleave**](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#cleave) (*PH* 92) [*et al.*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#great-cleave) Just drop the foe that was charged then attack another foe within reach.

However, I'm guessing the desire is for something more reliable. The prestige class [**war mind**](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/psionicWarMind.html#war-mind) (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 155-6) at level 5 gains the class feature sweeping strike:

> At 5th level, a war mind gains the ability to make great, sweeping swings with a melee weapon. On each melee attack a war mind makes, he can choose squares he threatens that are adjacent to each other, and his attacks apply to creatures in those two squares equally. A war mind can use this ability on any attack, even an attack of opportunity or a cleave attempt.
>
> A war mind cannot use this ability if he has moved more than 10 feet since the end of his last turn. If a war mind drops one or both of his foes with a sweeping strike, he can attempt a cleave normally; however, he makes only one cleave attempt per sweeping strike, even if he drops more than one foe.

Only 10 ft. need be moved to make a [charge](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#charge), which the special ability sweeping strike allows, especially if the DM doesn't count teleportation as movement. (For example, *Complete Psionic* has the base class ardent that *via* the Freedom mantle can take the 1st-level power *dimension hop* [psychoportation] (*CP* 83) that allows the ardent to take a swift action to teleport up to 10 ft.)

Alternatively—and many view the class as inappropriate for PCs—, the prestige class **warhulk** (*Miniatures Handbook* 22-4) gains at level 2 the special ability great swing:

> Starting at 2nd level, a war hulk is able to make a great, sweeping swing with a melee weapon. As a full-round action, the war hulk can choose three squares adjacent to one another (he must threaten all of them). His attack applies to all creatures in those squares. Make one attack roll and apply that roll as an attack against each defender. If the war hulk uses a special attack (such as disarm, trip, or sunder), this special attack affects only the first target; the other creatures are attacked normally.
>
> Walls and similar obstacles can block a great swing. Start with one square that the war hulk threatens. Each successive square chosen must be adjacent to the previous square and have line of effect from that square. Two squares separated by a wall, for instance, can’t be chosen as adjacent squares for a great swing.
>
> The war hulk may skip creatures, attacking only those he wants to. For example, if there are three creatures in a row—an enemy, an ally, and another enemy—the war hulk can choose those three squares for the great swing but strike only the two enemies.
>
> If a war hulk drops one of his foes with a great swing, he may make a cleave attack normally. However, he may do so only once for every time he swings, even if he drops more than one foe.

Don't despair! At level 4 this becomes the special ability mighty swing and usable during each of the war hulk's attacks, and at level 10 this becomes the special ability massive swing and affects *all* the squares the warhulk threatens!

However, in addition to having a requirement that the creature be size Large or bigger, the prestige class war hulk essentially obviates any ranks the creature's put into Intelligence-, Wisdom-, and Charisma-based skills, *and* the prestige class doesn't advance the creature's base attack bonus (instead it increases the creature's Strength by +2 at each level). (A DM that reads the charge action as a discrete special attack that just so happens to include attacking at the end may rule against the war hulk's level 4 mighty swing and level 10 great swing being usable at the end of the charge, but I think such a DM in the minority.)

That both prestige classes have *war* in their names is, I'm certain, just a coincidence.

Comment: @KRyan will probably have a superior answer—and probably some complete builds besides!—, but this should do for now. `:-)`

Comment: Since the OP mention the Warblade class, there is also the maneuver "Pouncing Charge" (Tome of Battle, p. 88) in the Tiger Claw School, but it's a lvl5 maneuver so needs a Initiator Level of 9.

Comment: @Luris Yep, that's totally legit. I'm gonna do some more research and see if there's anything else I can find before adding that to this answer. Thank you.

Comment: My memory fails me, but is Overrun not a thing in 3.5? In pathfinder there are overrun feats that let you hit all targets you run through, even while charging to an end target.

Comment: @Mayshar "It’s not possible to overrun as part of a charge," says the *Player's Handbook* errata.  Either *Pathfinder* was unaware of the *PH* errata to [overrun](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Overrun) or opted to ignore it.